# Best practice on combining a fragment in an activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

so I made a FragmentActivity with a google maps that tracks the user location on the map and move the camera wherever he goes.

The layout was pretty simple and I wanted a  map inside an navigation drawer activity. so I created a CoordinatorLayout inside the drawer layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.workshop.laps.MapsActivity" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Problem is that the java activity is now different, earlier i used **MapsActivity.java** that was responsible for tracking the user location. but now I use **MainActivity.java** the takes care of the drawer and not the map, so the application is showing a map but not tracking the user location.

Now, i can just copy the location tracking code to the new **MainActivity.java** but that just seem  not clean to me.
so my question is what's the best practice on that matter. copy java code to the new activity? or somehow activate the **MapsActivity.java** code from **MainActivity.java** (what feels right)

Thanks :)

Comment: post you `app_bar_main`...layout

Answer (score 0):

use CoordinatorLayout inside DrawerLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                                                                          
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.workshop.laps.MapsActivity" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```